# Accessing Kotlin Sealed Class from Java

Tags: java, kotlin, sealed-class

Up until now I have been using this Kotlin sealed class:

```
sealed class ScanAction {
   class Continue: ScanAction()
   class Stop: ScanAction()
   ... /* There's more but that's not super important */
}
```

Which has been working great in both my Kotlin and Java code. Today I tried changing this class to use objects instead (as is recommended to reduce extra class instantiation):

```
sealed class ScanAction {
   object Continue: ScanAction()
   object Stop: ScanAction()
}
```

I am able to reference this easy peasy in my other Kotlin files, but I am now struggling to use it in my Java files.

I have tried the following and both of these kick back compilation errors when trying to make reference to in Java:

```
ScanAction test = ScanAction.Continue;

ScanAction test = new ScanAction.Continue();
```

Does anyone know how I can reference the instance in Java now?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You have to use the `INSTANCE` property:

```
ScanAction test = ScanAction.Continue.INSTANCE;
```

Comment: In my case, I'm getting `Cannot resolve symbol 'INSTANCE'`